# No output from sum of Python regex list

Tags: python

The problem is to read the file, look for integers using the re.findall(), looking for a regular expression of '[0-9]+' and then converting the extracted strings to integers and summing up the integers.

MY CODE: in which sample.txt is my text file

```
import re
hand = open('sample.txt')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
print x
x = [int(i) for i in x]
add = sum(x)
print add
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: So what seems to be the exact problem then?

Comment: Please provide sample.txt. If is it a multiline file then I am wondering why you loop over each line but later on you only proces the last line.

Answer (score 6):

You need to append the find results to another list. So that the number found on current line will be kept back when iterating over to the next line.

```
import re
hand = open('sample.txt')
l = []
for line in hand:
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    l.extend(x)


j = [int(i) for i in l]
add = sum(j)
print add
```

or

```
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    print sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', f.read())))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re
hand = open("a.txt")
x=list()
for line in hand:
    y = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    x = x+y

sum=0
for z in x:
    sum = sum + int(z)

print(sum)
```